# IIS configurable http-headers for caching

Tags: iis, configuration, caching, iis-6

How would one configurably set http-headers to cache files in IIS >= 6?

Example:

- `*.cache.*` => cache nearly forever
- `*.nocache.*` => never cache

An example framework using this naming would be the GWT framework.

Comment: This is now the third time I've been searching for a solution to this...  it seems, the short answer is: "it's not possible in iis" (on a side not... is it just me, or does IIS caching config blow?).  Guess the workaround is to build cache busting into your build/deploy to append `?bust=[timestamp]` to the `.nocache.` files.  

`<script src="shirtdesigner/gwtapp.nocache.js?bustabuss=[timestamp]"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to setting the cache-control header.

See here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247404

Comment: At best, this applies to a directory (in IIS6). "You can specify these options in IIS through the CacheControlCustom property, which can be set for the entire server, a particular Web site, or a specific physical or virtual directory."  However with GWT, `*.cache.*` and `*.nocache.*` files live in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/23ea6f24-4b44-4fa0-a275-a1b907e1afb6.mspx?mfr=true

Explains the different methods of caching data in IIS.

Comment: Sorry, put up a 'wrong' question for what I needed.  In fact the term is better known as HTTP Expiration